# How to update the table of contents in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

On a *computer browser* I can update a Google Docs table of contents by clicking on the icon in the top-left corner of the table:

[image: Update table of contents]

How can I do the same in the Google Docs *Android app*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Google support on Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/116338?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1)

- You cannot insert a Table of contents on Android.
- *Add, change, or delete a table of contents* is only possible on a computer.